# Combining a loop function and IF condition in google app scirpt

Tags: loops, if-statement, google-apps-script

New to google app script and trying to create a function which combines loop (can be map, for or forEach) and IF condition.

See public spreadsheet for data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1V7CpCxBH0lg6wi1TAhfZJP5gXE8hj7ivQ8_ULxLSLgs/edit?usp=sharing

I wish to create an array inside a variable. In this array I want all quantity of column "D" but only if column "C" is "Buy".

This is the code I have tried but it comes back empty:

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const historySheet = ss.getSheetByName('Blad1');

function quantBuy () {
  const searchRange = historySheet.getRange(3,2,historySheet.getLastRow()-1, 2)
  let rangeValues = searchRange.getValues();
  for (i = 0; i < historySheet.getLastRow()-1; i++) {
    if (rangeValues[i] === 'Buy') {
      console.log(i);
  }}}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why can't you use the debugger to find it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

`getValues` is 2 demiensional

```js
function quantBuy () {
  const searchRange = historySheet.getRange(3,3,historySheet.getLastRow()-1, 2)
  let rangeValues = searchRange.getValues();
  for (let i = 0; i < rangeValues.length; i++) {
    if (rangeValues[i][0] === 'Buy') {
      console.log(rangeValues[i][1]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunatly, I do not get the expected result. This is my output:
( 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 9,  10, 11, .....32, 30). I would have expected to receive the number "14, 1, 3, 1, ........."

Comment: because this code prints the line where "Buy" is in any column. Try `console.log(rangeValues[i][j-1])` instead or something similar

Comment: Modified. Please check.

Comment: I am sorry but I tried both suggestion, not giving any result, as in no console.log result

Comment: Updated. I found that your `column` in `getRange` was wrong.